# Laravel - Progressive JPEGs are converting to baseline after resized

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-imagine

I am using CodeSleeve/stapler plugin in Laravel for image resizing.

I have noticed resized images are not progressive anymore.

As Stapler uses Imagine/Imagine Plugin for image handling, I am guessing I need to find solution in terms of imagine plugin rather then stapler.

Any help is appreciated.

My current configuration looks like this

```
$this->hasAttachedFile('profile_pic', [
            'styles' => [
                'large' => '800x360',
                'medium' => '500x230',
                'thumb' => '100x100'
            ]
        ]);
```

Comment: Why don't you try http://image.intervention.io/ for manipulating the images? And can you just tell me what happens after image is resized? What do you mean by it's not progressive anymore. If I understand that thing then maybe I can help you out with this.

Comment: @Siddharth Well actually, I am using laravel stapler which automate the process for resizing and uploading etc.. that's why. and when I say it's not progressive anymore, I am saying it based on this tool http://codepen.io/sergejmueller/full/GJKwv  .. before uploading it says images is progressive but after resizing through the plugin it says it's baseline jpeg..